# Is there a reference/cheat sheet for Rails generate command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

I am curious if there is some kind of reference or cheat sheet for the Rails **generate** command? Something that lists out all the possible generators (model, controller, migration, etc.) as well as options you can pass in for each (*--skip-migration*, etc.).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get all of this information on the command line.

- `rails generate` with no generator name will output a list of all available generators and some information about global options.
- `rails generate GENERATOR --help` will list the options that can be passed to the specified generator.

Comment: Is there something similar to Rails 4? There it just prints the rails help, no specific help for generate etc.

Comment: This seems fine to me on Rails 4.2: I tried `rails generate`, and got a list of generators, and then `rails generate <generator> --help` gave me specific generator help, e.g. `rails generate assets --help`.

Comment: You're right, I run the command out of the rails workspace by accident